# how where all columns in row (database)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, where-clause

how can where all `columns` in `row (database)` by `codeigniter`?
did this following code is `true`?

```
$this->db->get('mytable')->where('*', $id);
```

Comment: $fields = $this->db->list_fields('table_name'); ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to get the first matched row? If not would you please re-explain what you want.
Try something like:

```
$query = $this->db->
                select('title')->
                from('mytable')->
                where('*', $id)->
                limit(1)-> //Only want 1 row
                get(); //Get result
if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
    show_error('No rows to return'); //Exits, nothing after this will run
$row = $query->row(); //Gives you the first row, you can
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this one line code

`$result = $this->db->get_where(<table_name>, array(<field_name> => <check_value>));`

So, the code you are asking for would become

`$result = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('*' => $id));`

But I am not sure if the code you are asking for would work like this :|

Answer (score 0):

You can get all columns of a single row with this code

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$result = $this->db->get('mytable);
```

Or simply you can try this

```
$result = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);
```